# Nginx close keep-alive connection from php

Tags: php, nginx, http-headers, connection, keep-alive

**Hello Everybody**

I have trouble with nginx server . I have configured nginx with keep alive connection.

keepalive_timeout  65;

And connect to server with persistent connection , i send many request to server in same connection .

I want to close persistent connection from php.
php exit and die command closes response , not connection . And client can resend to server request in same connection .

simply, i want to close persistent connection from php

I use this command ,

header('Connection:close');

But not affected , connection is still alive

How can close http connection from php

Comment: your question is not clear, what is the error ?

Comment: I connect to server from cliend and send request and php run this code. 
header('Connection:close');

But this php code not close connection , the connection is still alive . 

I am using persistent connection from client to server

Comment: can you show us the nginx config, the php code and php-fpm config (since you are using nginx I guess you are also using php-fpm)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I took SO long to find the answer to this.

In PHP you need to call:

```
fastcgi_finish_request();
```

Comment: I've been looking for this for hours.

Comment: Thank you! This solved a big issue we had with a payment interface and a redirect to the bank's web page.

Answer (score 1):

From this [servfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/480181/65727) it seems you can try it by allowing this header in the nginx fastcgi handler.

```
fastcgi_pass_header Connection-close;
```

Comment: I am using this , but still connection is alive. 
I use persistent connection

Comment: Do you have the "Connection: close" header in the HTTP response headers? with a space after `: `. Try with `fastcgi_pass_header Connection-close;`, show headers.